# SQL Server Free Text Search vs In clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am currently using IN clause on a varchar field. Will using Contains of FTS help in performance?

For e.g.

```
Select * from Orders where City IN (‘London’ , ‘New York’)
```

vs

```
Select * from Orders where Contains (City, ‘London or New York’)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),City VARCHAR(100))
GO

INSERT INTO Orders 
VALUES ('London'),('Newyork'),('Paris'),('Manchester')
,('Liverpool'),('Sheffield'),('Bolton')
GO
```

**Create FTS on City Column using ID as the key**

```
 Used SSMS to create FTS Index.
```

**Queries**

```
-- Query 1
Select * from Orders 
where City IN ('London' , 'NewYork')
GO
-- Query 2
Select * from Orders where 
Contains (City, '"London" or "NewYork"')
GO
```

**Execution Plans for both queries**

[image]

As you can see The Query which used FTS costed 3 times more than the query which used IN Operator.

Having said this, when it comes to find Language specific terms in sql server FTS is the way to go, for example looking for Inflectional forms , Synonymous and much more <kbd>[Read Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)</kbd>  for more information.